# Symfony routing annotation requirement not working

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

## routing.yml

```
thisismyroute:
    path:      thisroute/to/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:createRoutePage }
    requirements: 
        page:  \d+
```

## controller

```
/**
     * Template Select
     * @Route("/to/{id}",name="thisismyroute", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */

    public function createRoutePage($id){

        /*   code here */

    }
```

when I access www.mysite.com/app_dev.php/thisroute/to/asdfasdf it is accessible when it shouldn't be because of the requirement set to integer.

In my routing_dev.yml I have the line

> _main:
>       resource: routing.yml

Answer (score 0):

For annotation settings it should be:

```
/**
 * Template Select
 * @Route("/to/{id}", name="thisismyroute", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */

public function createRoutePage($id)
{
    /* code here */
}
```

**UPDATE**

For yml configuration try

```
thisismyroute:
    path:      thisroute/to/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:createRoutePage }
    requirements: 
        id:  \d+
```

Comment: yes I also tried that "id" = "\d+" it still goes into the page when it shouldn't be i don't have any other routes going to /to/

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use the @Route annotation in controllers, it's easier to configure your routing.yml to import all routes annotated in your Controller directory once and for all, like this:

```
# import routes from a controller directory
route_group_name:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

That's it. This way you don't need to specify each route in the routing.yml.

Then you can only use annotations in your controller:

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/to/{id}", name="thisismyroute", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */

 public function myRouteAction($id)
 {
     /* code here */
 }
```

PS: it's also a Symfony recommended best practice to use annotations to declare routes.